# How can i implement this layout effectively?

Tags: xml, android-layout

i want to implement the as shown in the pic shown below how can i implement this effectively :

[image: my layout]

.

The layout consists of 4 cards and the view2 will be a calender,which should be arranged in the order as shown above.these should be in a scroll view .
i tried using table for cards but that didnt work out.
how can i make the cards adjust accordingly to the screen sizes.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `ConstraintLayout` with chains. See the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). The `ConstraintLayout` would contain your `CardView`s and it would all sit inside a `ScrollView`. The layout will adjust itself  nicely to different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The layout below auto-adjust to any screen size  ... without a scrollview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="75">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Card"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Card"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Card"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:text="Card"/>
        </LinearLayout>




        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:text="View"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```